# Find objects by pointing in a direction

Tags: vector, gps, location

I have a specific problem, and I find it hard to find a solution!

Using a GPS Device I can find my current position on earth. I need to be able to point to a direction (a compass on iPhone or similar device) and find what important objects (locations) are in that direction! Assume that I do have all those locations stored in a database.

Comment: You need to provide much more information than this. Are you accessing the device via some API? In that case, which API? Or is your application reading `$GPRMC` sentences directly from the device?

Comment: I am developing an Android application, which uses a local SQLite database, where it stores information about 'landmarks' in a my city. Each landmark has its latitude and longitude.  Now I want to use my built in compass, that will tell me on which direction I am pointing the device and show me what objects are in that direction.  So Java or C# code could be helpful.

Comment: I have used Haversine when I wanted to determine the distance between two objects. I think the answer is in trigonometry, though I have very modest knowledge on the field!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a location and a direction, your goal is to find what items in your database are adjacent to the location, in the appropriate direction.

Obviously, you could scan through every element in your database, and answer for each one, "Is this in the region?".  The real magic is efficiency; how you index the data in the database such that you can answer that question without having to examine every record.

A great example of this is in [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing).  However it's implementation does not handle direction, so you will need to filter the results.  You will use the database to get all objects within x distance of you, and will filter out those elements which are not in the appropriate direction.

If you cannot use a database engine with native geospatial indexing, you'll have to implement it yourself.  As mentioned in the comments, the Haversine function is used to compute distance on a sphere (in this case, the earth).  Rather than computing the distance between every point and yourself, you could begin by eliminating any elements which are grossly out of range, e.g. (your latitude + your search distance) < (the objects latitude).  Then use the Haversine to filter further.  You could also use a geospatial hashing function to do most of the work beforehand.

Once you have all of the elements within range, you can convert the x-y coordinates in your database into the polar coordinates.  In short:

```
arctan((item_y - users_y) / (item_x - users_x)) = the angle between the item and the user
```

If you compute this for every item within 'range' of the user, and filter out any elements which are not within some bounds of the compass angle (+/- 20 degrees, for example), you will get the elements you need.

If efficiency is still an issue, you can get more clever by immediately invalidating any elements which, for example are on the wrong side of the user (if the user is facing west, than any elements which have an x coordinate higher than the user cannot possibly be in his view).  Depending on your programming language, it may also be more efficient to use a static table of arctans with a lower degree of accuracy than is commonly provided.

If you are particularly clever, you may also find ways of indexing the data by angle, which will further lower the computation required.

Comment: Thanks Zack for this thorough answer. I will start to implement this solution, and post an update with my findings / source code.